# Apache phoenix count(*) query taking

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix

I'm using apache phoenix with hbase. But even a simple query like count(*) is taking around 2-3s.

Attaching screenshot for the reference 
[image]

Is this the expected response time or I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Could you post your execution plan:

```
explain select count(1) from GA_TABLE_1 where SF_ID='1';
```

But I would think that because of the  where clause you get some delay to make the calculation.